# Destination dropdown list automatically closes when clicking on scrolling mechanism to scroll down

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, input, focus, blur

IE11, when I focus the input, a drop-down list is displayed, when I roll the scroll bar of the drop-down list, the input is blurred.
I expect it to still focus input when I roll the scroll bar of the drop-down list.
With chrome, that is normal.
I use VueJS.
Thank you.

Comment: Please try to provide any sample code which we can try to run with IE to check for the issue. It is hard to assume that what actually you are doing in your code. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: This is my sample code: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/tuantai431997/fc0haj6y/). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I made a test with your code sample in IE 11. I find that after clicking on dropdown. list is displayed and while scrolling or after scrolling focus is still on the input. you can see that I can type in it which means it has the focus.

[image]

If you are talking about the flickering of the cursor in input than it looks like a bug.

If you are using any older version than it is advisable to use IE 11.

Comment: I roll by scroll bar in the right screen => dropdown hide

Comment: Looks like in IE it is changing the class makes the list hidden. I suggest you to try to assign the class from your js code may help to avoid this issue.